# Chrome extension to enable flash plugin

Tags: google-chrome

I am working for a game which runs in Adobe Flash. From Chrome 69, sites using Flash will require explicit permission to run it, every time the user restarts the browser. We are expecting lot of our players will get dropped off as they need to go through click-to-play flow every time they restart the browser.(Flash Roadmap -> https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap)

So we came up with an idea of using chrome extension which can enable flash plugin in background for our game website. We used 'chrome.contentSettings' for creating this extension.

Can someone please confirm if there is any roadmap plan from chrome to stop controlling of 'adobe-flash-player' plugin from 'chrome.contentSettings'.

Other words pls tell me how long below api code will work ?

*var flashResIdentifier; 
    chrome.contentSettings.plugins.getResourceIdentifiers(function(resIdentifiers) {
        for (var i=0; ihttps://abc.xyz.com/', 'resourceIdentifier':flashResIdentifier, 'setting':'allow'});*

Comment: If it works now, with the ephemeral flash setting, it will _probably_ keep working until Flash is removed entirely. You should prepare for some difficulty during _Flash Disabled by Default (Target: Chrome 76+ - July 2019)_, but it's impossible to say what.

Answer (score 1):

This will re-enable Flash manual white-listing 
in the latest Chrome 69+ and higher

chrome://flags/#enable-ephemeral-flash-permission

Set to DISABLED

then use Flash manual white-listing by going here:

chrome://settings/content/flash

Then manually add all website URL links
that you need like before 
in Chrome 68 and lower

Comment: They've removed that flag in Chrome 71

Comment: @Daredevil check my answer below. I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

After Chrome 71, you can persistently reenable flash for specific websites on Windows via a registry setting. Go to or create HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\PluginsAllowedForUrls, and add string values starting with a name of "1" and a value of the URL you wish to enable flash for (so, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\PluginsAllowedForUrls\1 = "http://myawesomesite.com/*" to enable Flash for everything under myawesomesite.com).

There is a similar setting for OSX and Android. See [here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#PluginsAllowedForUrls) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in version 72 of Chrome, and the solution I found is the following:

1. Click the paddlock icon, and go to **Site settings**:
   [image: Paddlock icon]
2. Then, on Flash option, select **Allow**
3. Refresh page, and that's all! :)

Reference: https://www.lifewire.com/enable-flash-in-chrome-4160696

Comment: Hi, regarding your solution, it works but once I closed the browser and open up again, I have to manually re-do the steps again. Is there a way to save it permenantly?

Comment: I think it's not possible :( I checked my Flash settings and it says: _"Your Flash settings will be kept until you quit Chrome."_