# How to programmatically enable flash in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Now that flash disabled by default in Chrome 75 our clients is having problems viewing our legacy content which was created using flash. I have referred to this SO question which had a couple of useful answers but for ease-of-use purposes, I'm leaning towards creating an extension that enables flash when a certain URL is accessed.

[Chrome extension to enable flash plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648273/chrome-extension-to-enable-flash-plugin)

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Flash Enabler",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Enable flash for Chrome",
"permissions": [
    "contentSettings"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://qa3.icomproductions.ca/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content_script.js"
        ]
    }
],
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/ice16.png",
        "32": "images/ice32.png",
        "48": "images/ice48.png",
        "128": "images/ice128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "images/ice16.png",
    "32": "images/ice32.png",
    "48": "images/ice48.png",
    "128": "images/ice128.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Here's a code based on that OP's snippet:

**content_script.js**

```
let flashIdentifier;

chrome.contentSettings.plugins.getResourceIdentifiers(indentifierArray => {
    indentifierArray.forEach(indentifier => {
        indentifier.id === 'adobe-flash-player' ? flashIdentifier = indentifierArray : flashIdentifier = null;
    });

});

chrome.contentSettings.plugins.set({ 'primaryPattern': 'https://qa3.icomproductions.ca/*', 'resourceIdentifier': flashIdentifier, 'setting': 'allow' });
console.log(flashIdentifier);
```

This generates an error saying:
[image: error meesage]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you also include the manifest?

Comment: I added the manifest and updated the links. Thanks!

Comment: The API should be used in background.js. Will close this question now.